# Gradient overlay move when cropping

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I have this file where my background layer has a gradient overlay. When I try to crop a different layer I want my background to remain the same as it was before cropping it. Instead the gradient overlay changes accordingly to my crop. I wonder if there is a way around this or should I merge my layers, so the background doesn't move?

*I'm using Photoshop CS6*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways around this:

1. Rasterize the gradient layer, so it becomes a bitmap layer.
2. Convert the gradient layer to a smart object. This is better since you can always go back and edit the gradient when necessary.

Comment: Will try later. Hope it helps, I don't wanna lose edit ability.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as accepted the answer that best solves your question; see [help] if you need to know more about the site and keep contributing!

Comment: Converting to smart object worked. I didn't thought of that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply un-check *Align with Layer* in the gradient overlay options.

Your gradient then isn't bound to the position or dimensions of the layer itself so you can crop or edit the layer without affecting the gradient. You can position and scale the gradient while the layer style dialog is still open by dragging the gradient in the document window and using the *Scale* slider.

[image: Gradient Overlay options]

Comment: Yes, at first I tried this but for some bizzare reason it didn't help.